# change password function

Tags: php, passwords

I have put together the follow code. But for some reason it refuses to update the database, and it keeps echoing the $error "Your current password is incorrect" no matter what is inputted.

Below is the main changepassword.php

```
    <?php 
include 'core/init.php';  //connection to database and checks user sessions
protect_page(); //useres not loged in cannot access this page

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('current_password', 'password', 'password_again');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'All fields marked with an * are required.'; //check that all fields are completed
            break 1;
        }
    }

    if (md5($_POST['current_password']) === $user_data['password']) { //if equal to current password
        if (trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])) {
            $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect';   //else append error
    }
}

include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>

<h1>Change Password</h1>
<p>Change your account password here.</p>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Your password has been changed';
} else {

    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password']);
        header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <ul>
        <li>
            Current Password*:<br>
            <input type="password" name"current_password">
        </li>
        <li>
            New Password*:<br>
            <input type="password" name"password">

        </li>
        <li>
            New Password Again*:<br>
            <input type="password" name"password_again">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="Change Password" />
        </li>
        </ul>

    </form>

<?php 
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Here is the changepassword function

```
//change password function
function change_password($membersID, $password) {
    $membersID = (int)$membersID;
    $password = md5($password);
    //update password in database
    mysql_query("UPDATE`members` SET`password` = '$password' WHERE`membersID` = $membersID");   
}
```

user_data is declared here

```
//user data variable to pass in sessionID and thus pass in their other details
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['membersID']; //picking up the particular user
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'membersID', 'username','password', 'forename', 'surename', 'email', 'age'); //picks up the fields declared here - MAKE SURE TO PASS ALL paramameters you need to output.
    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `$user_data['password']` come from? It isn't declared/used anywhere else on the page.

Comment: i have added it to the bottom of my question now buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is missing a quotation.

```
function change_password($membersID, $password) {
    $membersID = (int)$membersID;
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password));
    //update password in database
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$password' WHERE membersID = '$membersID';");   
    if (mysql_affected_rows > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    if(change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password'])) {
        // Redirect if change_password returns true
        header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
    } else {
        // Give some error message
    }
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
```

Try those changes, I don't know what way you want to handle the error if the change_password function returns false.

Comment: this plus other things help fixed it - cheers again david! can up rank you yet as i dont have enuff of a rank

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my first answer was incorrect, but the warning about MD5 still holds:

Keep in mind, that you password schema is very unsafe, there are some important points you should improve.

- The hash function MD5 is not apporpriate to hash passwords, because
  it is ways too fast, instead use a slow key-derivation function like
  BCrypt. I would invite you, to read more about this topic in my
  [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about secure password storage.
- Comparing password-hashes directly as you did, is only possible if no
  salt was used. An unsalted MD5 hash is not much safer than storing
  the password plaintext. Cracking your whole database with passwords containing less than 7 characters is a matter of e few seconds.
- The mysql* functions are deprecated, it is recommended to use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. Keep in mind that normally you have to escape string values in SQL statements (prepared statements or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`). Your example will be safe though, because the output of MD5 is always safe.

Comment: tried this change, still outputs the same error "Your current password is incorrect"

Comment: @RyanCollinsッ - Sorry my mistake. I would test the content of `$user_data['password']` first, it seems that it doesn't contain the stored password-hash. You can do it when you echo the error, simply add `echo $user_data['password']`.

Comment: I added that eco } else {
  $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect'; //else append error
  echo $user_data['password'];
 }
}

Comment: the password it echos' is the password in the database, where do i go from here?

Comment: @RyanCollinsッ - Does the database contain the plaintext password, or did you get the MD5 hash from the database?

Comment: @martinstoeckli, oh man sorry, you should have been the one I should say thank you to... :) Really nice tutorial... :) thanks!

Comment: @ultrajohn - Thanks for your compliment, glad you found it useful!